# Inline calendar using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How do I create an inline calendar in Excel using Apache POI like the JQuery datepicker (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?

Comment: Can you even create something like in Excel itself?

Comment: Yes, http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut07.htm & http://www.fontstuff.com/excel/exltut03.htm

Comment: Looks like in needs VBA macros. Can you not create a template file with those in it, then load that template in POI and populate it with your data?